# Site, sub-site and User level storage quota in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, user, quota, storage

can we put Site, sub-site and User level  quota in SharePoint Online !

Comment: no, only site collection level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far i know, you can set the Quota only for the Site collection not subsite level in SharePoint.

See the Set Storage Quota for site collection screen. Only thing is for site collection.
[image]

Read more about the set storage quota check this.[Manage site collection storage limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-site-collection-storage-limits-77389c2c-8e7e-4b16-ab97-1c7103784b08)

Another thing, for indivual User if they are using the One drive for bussiness then you can set the quota on it for specific user. You can increase it upto 1TB.

[SharePoint Online now allows up to 1TB of storage for OneDrive for Business and SharePoint site collections in Office 365](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/educloud/2014/03/19/sharepoint-online-now-allows-up-to-1tb-of-storage-for-onedrive-for-business-and-sharepoint-site-collections-in-office-365/)